# Random shuffle matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

how can I shuffle a vector consisting of  decimals and integers in matlab? I tried randperm() but it only operates on integers, furthermore it returns a vector of integers. thank you

Comment: Please read [ask], share your code  ...

Answer (score 3):

use `randperm` and the result as index to your existing vector:

```
a = [3.14 5 2.718 4]
ind = randperm (numel (a))
b = a(ind)
```

gives:

```
a =
   3.1400   5.0000   2.7180   4.0000

ind =
   2   3   1   4

b =
   5.0000   2.7180   3.1400   4.0000
```