# Is there any way to shuffle rows of a matrix without changing the frequency of each column?

Tags: matlab, random, shuffle

I have an NxR random matrix which has in each row shuffled 1:R.
I need another matrix with different sorts of shuffling in each row to have the same distribution of 1 to R for each column.
In other words, is there any way to shuffle rows of a matrix while keeping the frequency of each column the same?

I attached a screenshot of matrix B which I generated manually based on Matrix A.
[SS of matrix A and B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJFui.png)

Both have 1 to 4 in each row and the distribution of columns of A matches with columns of B. For example, in the first column of both matrices, there are two 1s, four 2s, one 3, and three 4s.

Is there any way to write an algorithm to generate the matrix B for larger dimensions?

The following is my code in which I tried my luck hoping I could get the solution from randomness, but I was unable to.

```
clear 
n=20;
r= 8;
A= cell2mat(arrayfun(@randperm, repmat(r, 1, n), 'UniformOutput', false)'); % a random mtx

%Frequency of each column
for i=1:r 
    F_A(:,i) = histcounts(A(:,i), r);
end



k=0;
while true

    B= A ;
for i=1:n
    idx = randperm(r);
    B(i, idx) = A(i,:) ;
end
    for i=1:r 
        F_B(:,i) = histcounts(B(:,i), r); %Frequency of each column
    end
    k=k+1;
    if sum(F_A == F_B, 'all') == r^2 || k >100000 % stop if frequency of A and B are similar 
        break
    end
end
sum(F_A == F_B, 'all')
sum(A==B, 'all')
```

Comment: Better add input and expected output, to help us understand what you mean. Also please tag a single language

Comment: Sorry, I edited and I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an `O(N^2*R/2)` time algorithm to solve this problem. It might sacrifice some randomness due to the nature of the constraints, but you can apply multiple iterations of the algorithm if you want higher degree of randomness. The run time of the algorithm is much better than the exponential time of random algorithm that has no guarantee of convergence.

The steps are simple,

1. Initialize `B` matrix as a row-shuffled version of `A`.
2. Walk throw all elements of `B` scanning row by row:

   - pick a random element `(i,k)` in the same row as the current `(i,j)` element
   - if the same `(i,j)` element is picked, skip to the next `(i,j+1)` element
   - search down in the `jth` and `kth` columns for the reversed pair `(l,k)` and `(l,j)`
   - now, we can interchange `(i,j)`,`(i,k)` and `(l,j)`,`(l,k)` without unbalancing the column frequency
3. Repeat step 2 if more randomness is required.

So, the idea is to randomly interchange two elements in the same row if there exists an exact reversed pair in another row below. This introduces an unbalance in two columns and is fixed by the reversed change in the other row below; the net change in column frequency will be zero.

```
clc, clear
rng(123)    % for reproducible outputs
N = 10;  R = 4;
A = zeros(N,R);
for i = 1:N
    A(i,:) = randperm(R);
end

% Initialize B as shuffled rows of A
B = A(randperm(N),:);
for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:R
        k = randi(R);                    % pick random element in the row
        if j == k, continue, end         % if same element, skip
        for l = i+1:N                    % search down for the 2 reverse elements 
            if B(l,[j k]) == B(i,[k j])  % if found
                B(l,[j k]) = B(l,[k j]); % replace the reverse elements
                B(i,[j k]) = B(i,[k j]); % replace the k, j elements
                break
            end
        end
    end
end
```

A sample output of 1 iteration:

```
A =
     3     2     4     1
     2     4     1     3
     3     2     1     4
     2     3     1     4
     2     1     3     4
     4     1     3     2
     4     2     3     1
     3     1     4     2
     4     3     1     2
     1     4     2     3
B =
     2     3     4     1
     1     4     2     3
     3     2     1     4
     4     1     3     2
     4     2     3     1
     2     3     1     4
     4     1     3     2
     3     2     1     4
     2     1     4     3
     3     4     1     2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution and comprehensive explanation!

Answer (score 0):

There are a matlab function [shuffle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.datastore.imagedatastore.shuffle.html?searchHighlight=shuffle&s_tid=srchtitle_shuffle_2), or you can take a look this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925290/random-shuffle-matlab).

Comment: Thank you. I have no problem with shuffling but keeping the frequency while shuffling. I added my code to the post.

Answer (score 0):

E.g., using the arrayfun( ) function to randperm( ) each column of A into a cell array result, then converting the cell array result into a single matrix:

```
[m,n] = size(A)
B = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(j)A(randperm(m),j),1:n,'uni',false))
```

A sample run:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Although you keep the frequency of each column the same, the frequency of each row will change.